# Bootup prompt for ecryptfs password

Tags: boot, prompt, fstab, ecryptfs

Is it possible to setup ecryptfs mounts to prompt for password upon bootup? Say for example /home and /var are ecryptfs folders that need to be mounted; how do I force a prompt upon bootup to ask for mount passwords?

Comment: This can depend on the distribution, what distribution are you using? Also, do you insist on ecryptfs, or will dmcrypt do? Ecryptfs is more geared towards mounting user directories, with the password supplied by the user, while dmcrypt is geared towards encrypting system areas, and the prompting would happen automatically with dmcrypt-aware installers.

Comment: Yes, dmcrypt would be the natural way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to use luks/dm-crypt and then modify `/etc/crypttab` file to do what I need.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please ?